# Find common preamble of a list of strings

Tags: strings, perl

Think of a set of text lines starting with a common string, e.g. indented code.

```
my $preamble = reduce {
    my $len = min(length $a, length $b);
    --$len while substr($a, 0, $len) ne substr($b, 0, $len);
    return substr($a, 0, $len);
} @lines;
```

Note that after the first invocation chances are high that `$a` already has the final result.

I'm wondering if there is a better approach in comparing the two strings in the reduce block. The while loop does not seem to be the best approach. It's also less readable since it does not convey the intent of the code (find common preamble of `$a` and `$b`).

**Update:**
After feedback from amon here is an alternative:

```
my $preamble = reduce {
    my $len = min(length $a, length $b);
    my ($current_prefix, $string) = (substr($a, 0, $len), substr($b, 0, $len));

    while($current_prefix ne $string) {
        chop $current_prefix;
        chop $string;
    }

    return $current_prefix;
} @lines;
```

I think this is an improvement in both performance and readability.

Comment: Can you provide `@lines` and `$preamble` sample?

Comment: Here is an example: http://ideone.com/3UVfcm

Comment: Instead of starting from right side of the string (and then choping), you can start from left side of it. It will make fewer while loops when `$preamble` is shorter string.

Comment: @mpapec I agree, I'd still like to find a better solution there.

Comment: If performance is absolute requirement, replace `reduce` with foreach equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think it is very good that you used `reduce`, as it clearly shows how the algorithm works. At least, to a reader who understands functional idioms.

One problem in your code is that you keep using `$a` and `$b`. These two names do not convey any meaning. We could do instead:

```
my $prefix = reduce {
  my ($current_prefix, $string) = ($a, $b);
  ...
```

Then, I would shorten the `$current_prefix` until it is at the beginning of the other `$string`:

```
until (0 == index $string, $current_prefix) {
  chop $current_prefix;
}
```

I did not use the statement modifier form of `until` or `while` – I don't believe that they make code much easier to read the way a postfix `if` or `for` can do. Note that the empty string occurs at the beginning of *any* string, so the termination condition of that loop is safe.

If you do not like `index` or `chop`, you could equivalently use the less efficient

```
until ($string =~ /\A\Q$current_prefix/) {
  $current_prefix =~ s/.\z//s;
}
```

Either way, the concept of shortening the prefix by removing one character at a time until it fits should be easier to read than all the `substr`inging you used.

Cutting the prefix to the length of the string would just be an optimization:

```
$current_prefix = substr $current_prefix, 0, length $string;
```

Put together, we would get the following code:

```
my $prefix = reduce {
  my ($current_prefix, $string) = ($a, $b);

  # the prefix cannot be longer than the string
  $current_prefix = substr $current_prefix, 0, length $string;

  # remove characters from the prefix until it occurs at the beginning.
  # "" is always a prefix, so the loop properly terminates.
  until (0 == index $string, $current_prefix) {
    chop $current_prefix;
  }

  return $current_prefix;
} @strings;
```

The code might be easier to understand for people who don't know `reduce` if you express it in the imperative form:

```
my ($prefix, @strings) = @original_strings;
for my $string (@strings) {
  # the prefix cannot be longer than the string
  $prefix = substr $prefix, 0, length $string;

  # remove characters from the prefix until it occurs at the beginning.
  # "" is always a prefix, so the loop properly terminates.
  until (0 == index $string, $prefix) {
    chop $prefix;
  }
}
# now $prefix is the prefix of all @original_strings
```

Oh look, it's shorter too!

Comment: `until (0 == index $string, $current_prefix)` is likely to perform worse than the original.

Comment: @200_success You have a point there (even after a match failure, other positions are searched), and we could use `until($current_prefix eq substr $string, 0, length $current_prefix)` or `until (0 == rindex $string, $current_prefix, 0)` to get around that. My answer *only* optimized for readability, not for performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Performance is an issue here, that's why I used `substr` and `ne` instead of `index`. However your answer made me realize that I don't need to preserve `$a` and `$b` (this is not a for loop) so I'm thinking of chopping both to size and compare them instead of using `substr`. Since `$a` is unlikely to change after line 2 I don't mind to have two `chop`s in the loop body...

Comment: Something like this: http://ideone.com/WvVX86 updating question...